# How to specify the menu string for "ok glass" launcher?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

For my GDK based app, how can I specify the string to display when user taps on the "ok glass" screen and flips through the menu items? e.g. there is "Take Picture" in that menu but the corresponding voice trigger string is "take a picture" as we can see when speaking out "ok glass".

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice#launching_glassware shows how to specify the voice trigger string.. is there an equivalent to specify the menu item string as well? For my app the voice trigger is longer than what fits in the menu screen so I'd like to use a shorter string for menu just like the 'Take Picture' case.

Answer (score 1):

For custom voice triggers (i.e., not the built-in ones), the strings for the touch menu and voice menu will currently be the same.

If you have multiple applications installed that respond to the same voice trigger, then a disambiguation menu will appear. The string that appears in this menu is the `android:name` attribute of the `<activity>` or `<service>` tag that has the voice trigger, or of the `<application>` if the activity/service doesn't specify one.

Comment: I was examining the Compass sample and it looks like Service that has the VoiceTrigger has the android:name of "com.google.android.glass.sample.compass.CompassService". It and the Application both have the label of "Compass Sample". But the launcher menu item has "Show compass". Perhaps there is another field that specifies this? And if the app doesn't have it, does it concatenate the first word with the last word? Since the voice trigger is "show a compass" and it becomes "Show compass".

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question -- I've updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: I thought along similar lines, that the 'a' would be removed from my voice trigger string.. But what I see is that only the first word gets auto capitalized so if my trigger is 'take a picture' then the menu shows 'Take a pict...' and not 'Take picture'.

Comment: I experimented with all different combinations of this too. When I substituted different words they call came out with the "a" in them. But "show a compass" was the only one that took out the "a" and became "Show compass".

Comment: When you use "take a picture" as your voice trigger, is it all lowercase, written exactly like that, but your app shows up separately in the menu? If so, please file a bug in our issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list